# Keep repeated max values in table

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

Tmux doesn't have a command to show windows in the active session. So I'm trying to parse Tmux's windows in the active session. I've got a unique table sorted by date (field 1).

```
#!/bin/sh
dump_tmux_info() {
    tmux list-panes -a -F "#{session_activity} #{session_name} #{window_index} #{window_name}"
}

# sort--> unique numbers descending (mru) --> unique fields3 (wind. order)
dump_tmux_info | sort -k1,1nr -u -k3 -u
```

Result:

```
1473706992 SessionF 1 windF
1473706992 SessionI 2 windO
1473706992 SessionZ 3 windO
1473706992 SessionZ 4 windB
1473699283 SessionZ 1 windZ
```

What I'm trying to do...

1. Match all fields based on [line 1,field 1] OR [line 1,field 2] OR max values in field 1 (either work) and remove the rest.
2. List matching window names in an ordered numeric array. `windF windO windO windB`

I've tried looking at AWK but I can't see how to access multidimensional arrays elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all the 4th-column values for the max value of column 1:

```
dump_tmux_info |
 sort -k1,1nr -u -k3 -u |
 awk '
    NR == 1 || $1 > max {max = $1; maxv = sep = ""} 
    $1 == max {maxv = maxv sep $NF; sep = " "} 
    END {print maxv}
 '
```

outputs

```
windF windO windO windB
```

Comment: I've tested this, and it works! Just to clarify, why does the statement `maxv = maxv sep $NF` default to the last field when it would substitute to maxv = "" " " 4. Does `$NF` move it to the last field?

Comment: `NF` without the dollar is the number of fields in the current record. Phrased differently, `NF` is the number of the last field. When you add the dollar, you get the *value* of the last field. Similarly, if you assign a number to a variable, then express the variable with a dollar, you get the value of that field: `echo "foo bar baz" | awk '{x=2; print x; print $x}'`

Comment: This lets you do interesting things, like get the *2nd last* value (`$(NF-1)`), or do things with *pairs* of fields: `for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {a=$i; b=$(i+1); some_function(a,b)}`